# Mysql JOIN a 3 status

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

a ver si alguien me aporta la luz.

- 3 tablas PRODUCTS , CATEGORIA, SUBCATEGORIA. las tres conun campo "status" (0,1)
- en PRODUCTS hay categoria_id (obligatoria) y subcategoria_id
- quiero una consulta que muestre los productos activos (status=1), de categorias activas, y de subcategorias activas, en el caso que la tenga. Y aquí es donde me pierdo.

La consulta de productos y categoria, me funciona, pero no veo como introducir las subcategorias y al ser posible que el campo esté vacio ya ni os cuento...

lo que tengo es esto:

```
$query = "SELECT products.* FROM products JOIN categoria ON products.categoria_id = categoria.id WHERE categoria.status='1' && products.status='1'";
```

Desde PHP claro...

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para unir una tabla que tenga o no filas relacionadas con otra, usamos los OUTER JOINs. Estos pueden ser LEFT, RIGHT y FULL. El más común será LEFT y es el que usaremos en esta ocasión.

La primer idea que se tiene al agregar la tabla es tratarla igual que otros joins, uniendo la tabla por sus llaves y agregando la condición al WHERE (cambié el `&&` por el estándar `AND`).

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM       products     p
INNER JOIN categoria    c ON p.categoria_id = c.id 
LEFT  JOIN subcategoria s ON p.subcategoria_id = s.id 
WHERE c.status = '1' 
AND   p.status = '1'
AND   s.status = '1'
```

Sin embargo, las filas sin relación con una subcategoría regresa `NULL` en todas las columnas y siempre regresa `desconocido` en cualquier comparación. Por lo mismo, termina actuando como un `INNER JOIN`.

Para poder agregar la condición de status, es necesario incluirlo en las condiciones del `LEFT JOIN`, por lo cual terminaría así.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM       products     p
INNER JOIN categoria    c ON p.categoria_id = c.id 
LEFT  JOIN subcategoria s ON p.subcategoria_id = s.id AND s.status = '1'
WHERE c.status = '1' 
AND   p.status = '1'
```

Ahora sí debe regresar los productos con status activo, categoría activa y, en caso de tenerla, subcategoría activa. Y si no tiene subcategoría solo toma las primeras dos condiciones.

Por último, puedes ver como modifiqué el formato de la consulta, agregué alias a tus tablas para no tener que repetir el nombre constantemente y agregué espacios en blanco y saltos de fila. Eso es una buena costumbre que te permitirá revisar el código más fácilmente. Una vez que tengas la consulta lista, ya la puedes agregar a tu código PHP (y de preferencia como procedimiento almacenado).

Comment: Primero, Gracias! Actualicé consulta que tenia hecha con el nuevo formato y manera que me comentas, todo ok,bueno como hasta ahora.. Probé las dos consultas que me propones, no me funcionan, en la segunda cambie : ON c.subcategoria_id = s.id AND s.status = '1 
por:  ON p.subcategoria_id = s.id AND s.status = '1
Y funciona igual queel codigo inicial.
Igual olvidé aclarar, quela subcategoria, es en realidad una categoria 2, queno se relaciona obligatoriamente con 'categoria', para poder usar varias en ambas direcciones.

Comment: Quiza voy a decir una burrada, lo expresaré en palabras. La parte de subcategoria deberia decir: "... y además si el 's.status' !=0' en donde el s.id sea = que p.subcategoria_id 

 Destacar que si no tiene subcategoria asignada, la p.subcategoria_id=0. pues tiene 0 por defecto en la DB.

Comment: Según lo que me dices, ¿tienes status diferentes a 0 y 1? Porque si no es así, es preferible usar la igualdad. En la referencia a la tabla, ya la corregí en la respuesta. ¿Debes mostrar productos con categoria con status 0 pero subcategoría con status 1?

Comment: Pues tengo la mala costumbre de usar !=, la voy a corregir desde ahora.
Status 0 es desactivado (no mostrar) y 1 activado (mostrar), lo puede tener el producto (ej: cocacola) la categoria (ej: Refresco) y la subcategoria "o categoria 2" (ej. Azucaradas). P.st=0, C.st=1, S.st=1 (no muestra la cocacola, pero muestra la Fanta).  P.st=1, C.st=0, S.st=1 ( no muestra ningun refresco)  P.st=1, C.st=1, S.st=0 ( no muestra refrescos con azucar, pero si Zero). La cosa no va de refrescos XD, así se entiende. Hay la posibilidad que producto no tenga declarada  subcategoria (=0), entonces ignore ese campo

Comment: Añade los datos de prueba y los resultados esperados en la pregunta, porque en los comentarios es más complicado leerlos.